# Twitter API searchtweets module error at line - result_stream_args=premium_search_args

Tags: python, api, twitter

There seem to be no key errors and valid credentials are in .twitter_keys.yaml file.  error showing up at line `result_stream_args-premium_search_args`

twitter_search.py file

```
from searchtweets import ResultStream, gen_rule_payload, load_credentials, collect_results

import requests

premium_search_args = load_credentials("~/.twitter_keys.yaml",
                                       yaml_key="search_tweets_premium",
                                       env_overwrite=False)


rule = gen_rule_payload("superbowl", results_per_call=100) # testing with a sandbox account
print(rule)

from searchtweets import collect_results

tweets = collect_results(rule, 
                         max_results=100, 
                         result_stream_args=premium_search_args)


# print(tweets.all_text)

[print(tweet.all_text, end='\n\n') for tweet in tweets[0:10]];
```

Getting the following error:

> C:\Users\hp\Dev\Twitter\twitter_search\src>python twitter_search.py
>
> Grabbing bearer token from OAUTH {"query": "superbowl", "maxResults":
>   100} Traceback (most recent call last):   File "twitter_search.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       result_stream_args=premium_search_args)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py",
>   line 308, in collect_results
>       return list(rs.stream())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py",
>   line 208, in stream
>       self.execute_request()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py",
>   line 263, in execute_request
>       resp = json.loads(resp.content.decode(resp.encoding))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\json__init__.py", line 354,
>   in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in
>   raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out to be the error was in the .twitter_keys.yaml file with the endpoint being incorrect.  The endpoint in this case should have been

```
endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/development.json
```

30day can be changed to full_archive etc.